# Как сгладить края чёрно-белой маски?

Tags: разработка-игр, графика, photoshop

На данный момент есть такая маска:

[image: Маска]

Как видно, края маски грубые и соответственно, вырезанное маской изображение так же получается с резкими границами.

Comment: может поможет blur?

Comment: Можно прогнать картинку через FXAA, но надо поискать его версию для изображений вне рендера.